# 401 (Unauthorized) error while using AutoDesk APIs

Tags: python, django, python-requests, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a Django application and I'm working with .stl, .stp and .igs files in it. I have to display these files in a HTML template and I'm trying to use the AutoDesk APIs for that. I have created an account first and authenticated but I'm getting trouble with displaying the images.

**here is the view which it contains authentication and uploading image to the bucket:**

```
def viewer(request):
    req = { 'client_id' : CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type' : 'client_credentials','scope':'code:all bucket:create bucket:read data:read data:write'}
    resp = requests.post(BASE_URL+'/authentication/v1/authenticate', req)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        TOKEN = resp.json()['token_type'] + " " + resp.json()['access_token']
    else:
        print('Get Token Failed! status = {0} ; message = {1}'.format(resp.status_code,resp.text))
        TOKEN = ""
    filepath = "C:/Users/imgea/desktop/"
    filename = '55.stl'
    my_file = Path(filepath + filename)
        #check package file (*.zip) exists
    if my_file.is_file():
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath + filename)
        # encoding the file name
        if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
            encodedfilename= urllib.pathname2url(filename)
        else:
            encodedfilename= urllib.parse.quote(filename) 
        resp = requests.put(BASE_URL + '/oss/v2/buckets/'+'bucket'+'/objects/'+ encodedfilename, headers={'Authorization': TOKEN,'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length' : str(filesize)},data= open(filepath+filename, 'rb'))
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            urn = resp.json()['objectId']
        else:
            print('Upload File to Bucket of Data Management Failed! status ={0} ; message = {1}'.format(resp.status_code,resp.text ))
            urn = "none"
    else:
        print(' ' + filename + ' does not exist')
        urn = "none"
    urn_bytes = urn.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(urn_bytes)
    base64_urn = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')

    headers = {
    'Authorization': TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    data = '{"input": { "urn": "' + base64_urn + '"},"output": {"destination": {"region": "us" }, "formats": [{ "type": "obj" }]}}'
    resp = requests.post(BASE_URL + '/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job', headers=headers, data=data)
    context = {
        'token': "'"+TOKEN+"'",
        'urn': "'"+urn+"'",
    }
    return render(request, 'viewer.html', context)
```

**here is the template:**

```
<body>
    <!-- The Viewer will be instantiated here -->
    <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>
    <!-- The Viewer JS -->
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Developer JS -->
    <script>
        var viewer;
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
                var accessToken = {{token|safe}};
                var expireTimeSeconds = 86400;
                onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
            },
            api: 'derivativeV2'    // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        };
        var documentId = {{urn|safe}};
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        });
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            // A document contains references to 3D and 2D geometries.
            var geometries = doc.getRoot().search({'type':'geometry'});
            if (geometries.length === 0) {
                console.error('Document contains no geometries.');
                return;
            }
            // Choose any of the avialable geometries
            var initGeom = geometries[0];
            // Create Viewer instance
            var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
            var config = {
                extensions: initGeom.extensions() || []
            };
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv, config);
            // Load the chosen geometry
            var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initGeom);
            var modelOptions = {
                sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
            };
            viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
            console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
        }
        function onLoadModelSuccess(model) {
            console.log('onLoadModelSuccess()!');
            console.log('Validate model loaded: ' + (viewer.model === model));
            console.log(model);
        }
        function onLoadModelError(viewerErrorCode) {
            console.error('onLoadModelError() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

According to these code blocks, I can get the access token and image urn successfully. At the same time, they are sent to the template correctly. But I got an error as
`{ "developerMessage":"Token is not provided in the request.", "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/", "errorCode": "AUTH-010"}`. How can I fix this issue and display the 3D files in HTML?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I haven't been solved it since last week. Same error but just not 3D viewer hope to figure out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when adding the token to the authorization header, you have to prefix the token with "Bearer ", so instead of `"Authorization": "<token>"` the header should be `"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"`.

Comment: Where exactly? In your code I see the line `TOKEN = resp.json()['access_token']` which is just the token without the "Bearer " prefix, and then the line that uploads your file to Forge says `resp = requests.put(BASE_URL + '/oss/v2/buckets/'+'bucket'+'/objects/'+ encodedfilename, headers={'Authorization': TOKEN,'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length' : str(filesize)},data= open(filepath+filename, 'rb'))`. Again, no "Bearer " prefix added there.

Comment: I have forgotten to add that in my question. I edited the question now.

Comment: And are you still getting the same "Token is not provided in the request." error? I've also noticed that you are uploading your file to a Forge bucket called "bucket". Are you sure you are the owner/creator of this bucket?

Comment: Yes I'm still getting the same error. And yes, I have created that bucket myself.

Comment: And there are actually other problems with the sample code, for example, after uploading the file to Forge you do not translate the file with the Model Derivative service. And the URN is not equal to `objectId`. URN must be base64-encoded.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to translate the file to .obj right now but I'm getting another error with that..

Comment: So are you actually trying to run a different code from what you've posted in the question? I'd suggest that you contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and include the actual python code you're trying to run, and if possible, your Forge app credentials as well so that we can debug it on our end.

Comment: I have added my view's newest version to the question. I have converted the urn to base64 and I have tried to translate the file but I got `{'diagnostic': 'Failed to trigger translation for this file.'}` error.

Comment: So you're not getting an authentication error anymore?

Comment: Can you please post the content of the `base64_urn` variable?

Comment: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2ZtLzU1LnN0bA==

Comment: Thanks. This URN is not referencing any file in a bucket called "bucket" as your python code snippet indicates. Are you sure you are running the exact same code that's shown here? And are you not getting the authentication error anymore? Again, we need more clarity in order to support you, so I'd recommend contacting us via the email address I mentioned earlier, with the *exact* code you are trying to run.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm writing you via e-mail.